# Make second PyQt4 QMainWindow "detachable" from main application

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a PyQt4 application with a QMainWindow. From within that program I launch another QMainWindow that is used to draw a matplotlib plot. My approach is based on Eli Benderskys [way](https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/master/2009/qt_mpl_bars.py) of integrating matplotlib with PyQt.

```
class QtMatplotlibWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
"""Plot window to display data, is created by main application"""

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
```

If I instantiate `QtMatplotlibWindow` with `parent=None` the resulting window will be completely "independent", meaning that it has its own icon in the taskbar and is completely "detached" from the main application. So, for instance, I can bring anther application, say Internet Explorer, to the front and subsequently bring only the Matplotlib window to the front, the actual application staying in the background. However using `parent=None` results in the matplotlib window being thrown off the stack and closed without my willing to do so at some seemingly random point in time.

If, on the other hand, I pass the instance of the main application as the parent the two windows are "tied together", meaning that I cannot view them independently of each other.

How can I achieve the "best of both worlds"? I'd like to pass the instance of the main application as the parent, so that the generated plots will only be closed if I close the main application, but I would also like the plot windows to be entirely independent in showing and moving. I would expect there to be some property of QMainWindow that would allow me exactly that. I hope I could phrase my question clear enought, I feel like I lack the appropriate terminology.

Comment: The fact that your second window disappears at random time indicates that it has been garbage collected. You must keep a python reference to all your windows. For instance append your newly created window to a list somwhere in your application: `windowlist.append(QtMatplotlibWindow())`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I am looking for. Would you consider turning your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your second window disappears at random time indicates that it has been garbage collected. You must keep a python reference to all your windows. For instance append your newly created window to a list somwhere in your application: `windowlist.append(QtMatplotlibWindow())`